# How to convert SQL function to HQL function via JPA?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, hql

I have a SQL query that contains a function which runs correctly in the Database.  Within my application I'm using HQL with JPA Entity classes and this function is now giving me an error.  I have converted other sql queries to hql fine, it's just this function that's giving me an issue.  Can someone give me insight as to what changes I need to make in order to make this HQL query/function work?

**ERROR**

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode
 -[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'contact_info.f_user_details' {originalText=contact_info.f_user_details}
    -[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
       +-[QUOTED_STRING] LiteralNode: ''ContactInfo''
       +-[QUOTED_STRING] LiteralNode: ''UserDetails''
       +-[DOT] DotNode: 'contactinf1_.USER_ID' {propertyName=userId,dereferenceType=ALL,propertyPath=id.userId,path=c.id.userId,tableAlias=contactinf1_,className=database.tables.ContactInfo,classAlias=c}
       |  +-[DOT] DotNode: 'contactinf1_.USER_ID' {propertyName=userId,dereferenceType=2,propertyPath=id.userId,path=c.id.userId,tableAlias=contactinf1_,className=database.tables.ContactInfo,classAlias=c}
       |  -[IDENT] IdentNode: 'userId' {originalText=userId}
       -[NUM_INT] LiteralNode: '0'

**HQL**

```
select p.firstName, p.lastName, 
contact_info.f_user_details('CONTACT_INFO','CONTACT_INFO.UserDetails',c.id.userId, 0) as details"                   
                from Personnel p, 
                ContactInfo c, UserDetails ud            
                where p.userId = c.id.userId 
                and ud.userId = p.userId;
```

**SQL**

```
 Select p.FIRST_NM, p.LAST_NAME,
 contact_info.F_USER_DETAILS('CONTACT_INFO','CONTACT_INFO.USER_DETAILS',ud.USER_ID,0) as USER_DETAILS
      from PERSONNEL p 
      inner Join CONTACT_INFO c
      On p.USER_ID = c.USER_ID
      inner join USER_DETAILS ud
      on ud.USER_ID = p.USER_ID
```

Comment: Read the HQL documentation, you would need to use inner join in the same fashion you have used in your SQL query.

Comment: Just imagine the path that is being taken here: having SQL, trying to "convert" that to HQL and then the persistence provider has to convert that back into SQL again in the end. You might as well just use nativeQuery() directly